# How to: Make an array with a max of 7 objects, yet the values are randomized

Tags: java, arrays

My problem is not creating the array, with a max object hold of 7. Nor, an array of ONE random number. My problem here is creating the array with both a maximum hold of objects as 7, and all as random numbers. I know i need to use a loop for this to create seven random `int`s.

```
   Random rnd = new Random();

   int size = 0; //Will be used for me to increment seven times once 
                 //i get this figured out.

   int[] array = new int[7]; //Max hold of seven objects.
   System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

Comment: So what's the problem?  If you know you need to use a loop, then use one.  If you can't get it to work, show us the loop you've tried.

Comment: Sorry, should be more clear. I don't know how to manipulate the values of the objects INSIDE the array. This is my problem. I can't even go about creating a loop for it. I use a for loop, but since I cannot randomize the values it always is just repeating an Array: [0,0,0,0,0,0,0] instead of creating seven random integer objects and populating my array with the returned integers.

Comment: Are you saying you don't know how to change one value of the array?  It's `array[i] = <the new value>;`.  `i` must be from 0 to 6.

Comment: I'm still learning Arrays, on my own time; outside of work. I've investigated several methods. I'm currently trying the Array.fill() method. But I will try this also. What is i? Do, I need to declare it first? Or is it its own method withing Java.Array imports?

Comment: @DancingDylan I think what ajb called `i` you've called `size` based on the comments in your code.

Comment: `i` is some value.  I didn't mean literally to use `i`.  It can be a constant like 0 or 3 or something, or it an be an expression, which could be a single variable.  If you want to use a variable, you'll have to declare it first.  If you write a `for` loop like `for (int i = 0; .......)`, that declares `i` for you.  If this is confusing, then you really need to step back and go through some beginning tutorials.

Comment: @ajb Well... I feel VERY ignorant at this moment. I appreciate your help greatly. I'll bookmark with method for later recognition. Thank you very much, I just figured it out using this method and a basic for loop. Much thanks.

Comment: @ajb One question. how could i access these values? Such as [2,4,12,8,19] If i would want to access 4, how could i print this out? Or use it to multiply a different variable in my program,

Comment: `array[1]` equals 4.  `array[0]` equals 2, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

By default array elements are assigned 0 with the initialization `int[] array = new int[7];`
That is why you're getting a set of zeros.

You could create a random integer and assign it to an array element as follows,

```
    int[] array = new int[7];
    Random ran = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {            
        array[i] = ran.nextInt();
    }
```

There are many methods that will help you to create a Random integer.
Refer [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random--).
Hope this helps.

Comment: @DancingDylan : Glad you solved it. Please mark the answer as correct, so the question will be visible as resolved.